# Set Mirth destination to send transform data back as a custom ACK

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

I have a Mirth channel that set up as a web service listener, it receives an ID, build an HL7 query message and send this query and eventually get back an HL7 response.

- Channel Name: QueryChanel
- Source Connector Type: Web Service Listener
- Destination Connector Name: QueryToVista
- Destination connector Type:LLP Sender.

This is the typical HL7 response I receive back from my query is as follow:

```
MSH|~|\&|VAFC RECV|FACILITY|VAFC TRIGGER||20121011141136-0800||ADR~A19|58269|D|2.4|||NE|NE|USA
MSA|AA|1234|
QRD|20121011051137|R|I|500000001|||1^ICN|***500000001***|ICN|NI|
EVN|A1|20121004064809-0800||A1|0^^^^^^^^USVHA\\0363^L^^^NI^TEST FACILITY ID\050\L|20121004064809-0800|050
PID|1|500000001V075322|500000001V075322^^^USVHA\\0363^NI^VA FACILITY ID\050\L~123123123^^^USSSA\\0363^SS^TEST FACILITY ID\050\L~9^^^USVHA\\0363^PI^VA FACILITY ID\050\L||JOHN^DOE^^^^^L|""|19800502|M||""|""^""^""^""^""^^P^""^""~^^""^""^^^N|""|""|""||S|""||123123123|||""|""||||||""||
PD1|||SOFTWARE SERVICE^D^050
ZPD|1||||||||||||||||""
```

I can get all the above to return if I set my Source's Response From parameter to **QueryToVista**

However, I want to return only the value ***500000001*** from the above message.  I've tried to play around with the transformer in the QueryChanel destination without success.

***Update:***

I tried to add a javascriptwriter connector after the QueryToVista connector in the same channel as follow:

```
   var destination = responseMap.get('QueryToVista');
   var responseMessage = destination.getMessage();

   //Fails with following error: TypeError: Cannot read property "QRD.4" from undefined
   var customack = ResponseFactory.getSuccessResponse(responseMessage['QRD']['QRD.4']  ['QRD.4.1'].toString())**


   //work but send the whole HL7 message
   var customack = ResponseFactory.getSuccessResponse(responseMessage.toString())**


   responseMap.put('Barcode', customack);
```

I can't seem to use the normal transformation to retrieve the element at all. 
Thank you.

Comment: Did you do anything special to send the ack message from the LLP Sender to the Javascript writer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track, but your update illustrates a couple of issues. However, your basic approach of using two destinations is valid, so long as "Synchronize channel" is checked on the Summary tab.

### Issue 1

In your example, the HL7 response you are wanting to parse is in pipe delimited HL7 form. In order to access the elements using E4X notation (eg. responseMessage['QRD']['QRD.4']['QRD.4.1']) you must first convert it into an E4X XML object. This can be done in two steps.

- Convert the pipe delimited HL7 string into an XML string.
- Convert the XML string into an E4X XML object

In a Javascript transformer of the JavaScript Writer (not the Javascript Writer script itself)

```
var response = responseMap.get("QueryToVista");
var responseStatus = response.getStatus();

// Get's the pipe delimited HL7 string
var responseMessageString = response.getMessage();

if (responseStatus == "SUCCESS")
{
    // converts the pipe delimited HL7 string into an XML string
    // note: the SerializeFactory object is available for use in transformer
    //       scripts, but not in the Javascript destination script itself
    var responseMessageXMLString = SerializerFactory.getHL7Serializer(false,false,true).toXML(responseMessageString);

    // convert the XML string into an E4X XML object
    var responseMessageXMLE4X = new XML(responseMessageXMLString);

    // grab the value you want
    var ack_msg = responseMessageXMLE4X['QRD']['QRD.4']['QRD.4.1'].toString();

    channelMap.put('ack_msg', ack_msg)
}
else
{
    // responseStatus probably == "FAILURE" but I'm not sure of the full range of possibilities
    // take whatever failure action you feel is appropriate
}
```

### Edit****

I don't believe there is an Issue 2. After reviewing your own approach, I played a bit further, and believe I have confirmed that your approach was indeed correct for generating the SOAP reponse. I'm editing this section to reflect simpler code that still works.

In the Javascript Writer script

```
var barcode = channelMap.get('ack_msg');
var mirthResponse = ResponseFactory.getSuccessResponse(barcode);
responseMap.put('Barcode', mirthResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much csj,

I played around and got mine to work and looking at your solution, you pointed out my bottle neck to the issue as well which is the XML part, I did not realize you have to cast it into XML as per the new XML when you already call toXML function :)

Here is my script, though basic I thought I post it up for anyone find it useful down the road.

```
var destination = responseMap.get('QueryToVista');
var responseMessage = destination.getMessage();
var Xmsg = new XML(SerializerFactory.getHL7Serializer().toXML(responseMessage));

var xml_msg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'+
              '<XML><Patient Name="'+Xmsg['PID']['PID.5']['PID.5.1']+
              '" Barcode="'+Xmsg['QRD']['QRD.8']['QRD.8.1']+'" /></XML>';

var sResp = ResponseFactory.getSuccessResponse(xml_msg)

responseMap.put('Response', sResp);
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. I completely understand the confusion of .toXML not actually returning an XML object. The method would probably be more aptly named .toXMLString